# Rails Duplicate key error: How to tell Rails to continue with the ID from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently deploying a Ruby on Rails web application with `Postgres`. I'm working with `Docker`, just to say it.

When I deploy my application, I insert some predefined data into the database. When I want to create a new record, I get a `duplicate key error`.

**Full error message:**

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "modelname_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists
```

How can I solve this? How can I tell Rails to continue with the `primary key` from the last record?

Comment: Do you need special IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can check insert_all method from Rails 6. If you are in lower versions of Rails use activerecord-import gem.

In case of insert_all

First form the json

```rb
new_records = [{id: 1, name: 'steve'},{id: 2, name: 'george'}]
Model.insert_all(new_records)
```

This will insert records if its not already there and ignore if records are there.

In case of activerecord-import

```rb
new_records = [{id: 1, name: 'steve'},{id: 2, name: 'george'}]
Model.import new_records, on_duplicate_key_ignore: true
```

references:
[activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)
[rails-6-insert_all](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/11/26/rails-6-insert-all.html)

Comment: This will still break if ID 1 or 2 are already taken.

Comment: This will ignore the new changes if id already exists if data needs to be updated then upsert_all or upsert can be used rails 6 and for activerecord-import we can use the flag on_duplicate_key_update: [attributes_that_needs_to_be_updated] instead of on_duplicate_key_ignore: true

Comment: If you use `on_duplicate_key_ignore` the imports quietly fail and you don't know what's occupying those IDs. If you use `on_duplicate_key_update` you've replaced existing rows which might already have associations. If you really need those specific IDs (and this is showing how that gets complicated) it's probably safer to delete them first to ensure they're truly wiped and then import.

Comment: on_duplicate_key_update will update only the attributes we specify, so it won't update any ids unless it is specified. Depending upon the needs on_duplicate_key_ignore or on_duplicate_key_update can be used

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an ID the database will choose one for you.

```
person = Person.create!( name: "MacReady", thing: false )
```

If you need to reference a specific ID, reconsider that. Relying on special IDs is too fragile, as you're discovering. Database IDs should be considered unique identifiers with no further special meaning.

For example, instead of remembering that "user ID 1 is the admin user" add an "admin" field.

```
admin = User.create!( name: "Yarrow Hock", admin: true )
```

Now you can check `if user.admin` for any user, have as many admins as you want, and change whether a user is an admin at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can also resolve your problem. Add this in your staging or preprod console (I am using Heroku for this so I added in my heroku rails console):

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection.execute("SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), MAX(id)) FROM table_name;")
```

Check out this [blog](https://blog.kiprosh.com/activerecord-recordnotunique-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-key-already-exists/) for more info and how this is been generated.